# Multiple argument URLs in Django

Tags: python, django

Trying to create a simple forum. How would I create a hierarchical set of named URLs in Django 1.9? The docs say to do it like this:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
```

Which I did, as:

```
url(u'^(?P<Name>.*)/(?P<ThreadName>.*)/$', views.thread, name = "thread"),
```

and in views.py:

```
def thread(request, Name, ThreadName):
board = get_object_or_404(Board, Title = Name)
thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, Title = ThreadName)
context = { "board": board,
            "thread": thread,
            }
return render(request, "post/board.html", context)
```

but I get an error saying that "No Board matches the given query.", even though the board exists and I can get to it at site/Name, it only fails at site/Name/ThreadName.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the capturing part *non-greedy*. Replace:

```
url(u'^(?P<Name>.*)/(?P<ThreadName>.*)/$', views.thread, name = "thread"),
```

with:

```
url(u'^(?P<Name>.*?)/(?P<ThreadName>.*?)/$', views.thread, name = "thread"),
```

Note the `?` characters - they make all the difference.

---

Or, depending on what are the valid characters for the name and thread name, you can look for one or more *alhanumeric* (`\w+`) instead of any character:

```
url(r'^(?P<Name>\w+)/(?P<ThreadName>\w+)/$', views.thread, name = "thread"),
```